# Prove that $(\sup\{y\in\Bbb R^{\ge0}:y^2\le x\})^2=x$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, foundations

This question is a simple one from foundations of analysis, regarding the definition of the square root function. We begin by defining

$$\sqrt x:=\sup\{y\in\Bbb R^{\ge0}:y^2\le x\}:=\sup S(x)$$

for $x\ge0$, and now we wish to show that it satisfies its defining property, namely $\sqrt x^2=x$. By dividing into cases $x\le1$ (where $1$ is an upper bound for $S(x)$) and $x\ge1$ (where $x$ is an upper bound for $S(x)$), we know $S(x)$ is upper bounded and hence the function is well-defined for all $x\ge0$.

It follows from the intermediate value theorem applied to $f(y)=y^2$ on $[0,\max(1,x)]$ that $\sqrt x^2=x$, if we can prove that $f(y)$ is continuous, but suffice it to say that I would like to prove the IVT later in generality, when I will have the definition $|x|=\sqrt{xx^*}$ (which is used in the definition of continuity), so I hit a circularity problem. Thus I need a "bootstrap" version of the IVT for this particular case, i.e. I can't just invoke this theorem.

What is the cleanest way to get to the goal here? Assume I don't have any theorems to work from except basic algebra.

Comment: You don't need to define $|x|$ that way. Just use the usual definition. $|x|=x$ for $x\geq0$ and $-x$ for $x<0$. Or better, distance between numbers $a$ and $b$ is $\max(a,b)-\min(a,b)$. With distance you can define limits, derivative, etc.

Comment: @Mario Carneiro I suggest you tag it *elementary set theory* too. Asaf should know this and I'm not sure he gets alerts for the tag *foundations*.

Comment: @Franklin.vp I know this, but I want to define it later as $|x|=\sqrt{xx^*}$ and use that to prove a nice, general form of IVT. In practice, it shouldn't make too much difference for this proof; it just means that this proof will use ${\rm if}(x\ge0,x,-x)$ instead of $|x|$. But I can't prove this general IVT yet - I want to tailor it to the specific characteristics of the $x^2$ function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have the l.u.b. axiom, you can use that, for any two bounded sets $A,B$ of nonnegative reals, we have 
$$(\sup A) \cdot (\sup B)=\sup( \{a\cdot b:a \in A,b \in B\}).$$
Applying this to $A=B=S(x)$ we want to find the sup of the set of products $a\cdot b$ where $a^2\le x$ and $b^2 \le x.$ First note any such product is at most $x$: without loss assume $a \le b$, then we have $ab \le b^2 \le x.$ This much shows $\sqrt{x}\cdot \sqrt{x} \le x$ for your definition of $\sqrt{x}$ as a sup.

Second, since we may use any (independent) choices of $a,b \in S(x)$ we may in particular take them both equal, and obtain the products $t\cdot t=t^2$ which, given the definition of $S(x)$, have supremum $x$, which shows that $\sqrt{x}\cdot \sqrt{x} \ge x$.

Comment: Could you explain your claim that $(\sup A)(\sup B)=\sup(A\cdot B)$? That's not obvious to me. I think I see one direction: if $ab\in A\cdot B$, with $a\in A$ and $b\in B$, then $a\le\sup A$ and $b\le\sup B$, so $ab\le(\sup A)(\sup B)$. Thus $(\sup A)(\sup B)$ is an upper bound for $A\cdot B$, so $(\sup A)(\sup B)\ge\sup(A\cdot B)$.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro One sketch: Pick $x_n \to \sup A$ and $y_n \to \sup B$, in each case approaching the sups strictly from below. Then by definition of sup there are $a_n,b_n \in A,B $ with $x_n\le a_n$ and $y_n \le b_n$. Then $x_ny_n\le a_nb_n$, and as $n \to \infty$ this gives a sequence of products $ab$ approaching the product of the sups.

Comment: One interesting connection: This is often used as the *definition* of multiplication in Dedekind-cut constructions of the reals.

Comment: Okay, so I've got down to the last part of the proof (your proof sketch has been very helpful), where we prove $\sqrt x^2\ge x$. I have proven $\sup A\cdot\sup B=\sup AB$, so this reduces to $\sup (S\cdot S)\ge x$. Since $\{t^2|t\in S\}\subseteq S\cdot S$, it suffices to prove $x\le\sup\{t^2|t\in S\}=\sup\{y^2|y^2\le x\}$. But how do we know that $\sup\{y^2|y^2\le x\}=x$? Perhaps there is a gap below $x$ such that no real number squares to this range.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro  The set of squares of rationals is dense in the reals. Consider a fixed denominator n  and the squares $1/n^2 ,4/n^ 2 ,...,n^2 /n^2 .$  The maximum difference between successive terms is less than 2/n . Taking arbitrariloy large $n$ then shows the squares of rationals are dense in (0,1] . Then using reciprocals it follows the squared rationals are also dense in (1,∞).

Comment: Cool, I completed the proof! I used a slightly more direct modified argument for the proof $(\sup S)^2\ge x$: Use reciprocals to reduce the problem to $(0,1]$. Then if $(\sup S)^2<x$, let $\epsilon=\frac13(x-(\sup S)^2)\le\frac13\le1$ (since $0<x-(\sup S)^2\le1$). Then $(\sup S+\epsilon)^2=(\sup S)^2+\epsilon(2+\epsilon)\le(\sup S)^2+3\epsilon=x$, so $\sup S+\epsilon\in S$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x):=\sqrt{x}:=\sup(y| y^2\leq x)$.

As pointed in the comments existence of supremum implies the Archimedean property: If there is $x$ such that for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $x>n$ then there is a supremum $y$ of $\mathbb{N}$. But then there is $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n>y-1$, from where $\mathbb{N}\ni n+1>y$. Which is a contradiction. Therefore we have:

**Archimedean property:**
For every $x$ there is $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n>x$.

The Archimedean property is very comfortable to use because from there we can apply the proof about limits etc. that we are used to in Calculus.

**Since supremum is minimal bound:**

For every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there is $y_n$ such that $y_n^2\leq x$ and $y_n>f(x)-\frac{1}{n}$. We can take $n$ such that $f(x)-\frac{1}{n}>0$ (Archimedean property). Square both sides of $y_n>f(x)-\frac{1}{n}$ to get $$x\geq y_n^2>(f(x)-\frac{1}{n})^2$$. We have that $f(x)^2$ is an upper bound of all $(f(x)-\frac{1}{n})^2$.

We prove now that is the minimal bound. For every $e>0$ take $n$ such that $n>\frac{2f(x)}{e}$ (Archimedean property). Then $e\geq \frac{2f(x)}{n}>\frac{2f(x)}{n}-\frac{1}{n^2}$, from where $f(x)^2-e<f(x)^2-\frac{2f(x)}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}=(f(x)-\frac{1}{n})^2$. Hence $f(x)^2$ is the minimal bound of the $(f(x)-\frac{1}{n})^2$.

From the above displayed inequality $x$ is an upper bound of the $(f(x)-\frac{1}{n})^2$ and therefore it is larger than its supremum, i.e. we get that $x\geq f(x)^2$.

Now we need to get the other inequality.

**Since supremum is a bound:**

For every $n>0$ we have $(f(x)+\frac{1}{n})^2> x$, otherwise $f(x)$ is not an upper bound of $(y|y^2<x)$. Now we need to show that $-f(x)^2$ is the supremum of $-(f(x)-\frac{1}{n})^2$. This will imply that $-f(x)^2\leq-x$, i.e. $f(x)^2\geq x$. I put the minus sign to use that we have supremum of bounded sets, but of course it happens likewise for infimum. Now we proceed as before. Let $e>0$ and take $n$ such that $n>\frac{1}{e}$ then $n^2>\frac{1}{e}$ or $e>\frac{1}{n^2}>-\frac{2f(x)}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}$. Hence $-f(x)^2-e<-f(x)^2+\frac{2f(x)}{n}-\frac{1}{n^2}=-(f(x)-\frac{1}{n})^2$. Thus, $-f(x)^2$ is the minimal bound of the $-(f(x)-\frac{1}{n})^2$, and therefore the supremum. QED.

Comment: You are using continuity of $x^2$ implicitly in this argument. (Why does $\forall e>0,x\ge (f(x)-e)^2$ imply $x\ge f(x)^2$?)

Comment: I don't define the reals; I am using an axiomatic treatment (the important one is the supremum axiom: any upper bounded set $\emptyset\subset S\subseteq\Bbb R$ has a least upper bound $\sup S\in\Bbb R$).

Comment: I neglected to mention the field axioms (which exclude $\Bbb N$ as a model of the axioms).

Comment: I don't follow your nested interval property argument. I just looked up nested interval property, and I found a theorem that the intersection of countably many nested closed intervals is nonempty and closed. But that's not good enough, because it doesn't guarantee the intersection is a singleton, which is what you want.

Comment: The supremum axiom proves that $\Bbb R$ is archimedean: Suppose that there is a real number $x$ greater than every natural number. Then $x$ is an upper bound on $\Bbb N$, so let $y=\sup\Bbb N\in\Bbb R$. By definition, there is a natural number $n>y-1$ (otherwise $y-1$ would be an upper bound), so $y<n+1\in\Bbb N$, a contradiction.

Comment: OK, now I rewrote the proof in using the Archimedean property. I will delete the comments to clean this up.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A=\sup S(x)=\sqrt x$. (We wish to show $A^2=x$.) By the AM-GM inequality, $\frac12(A+\frac xA)\ge\sqrt x$. Here's the algebraic proof of this claim:

$$0\le\Big(A-\frac xA\Big)^2=A^2-2x+\frac{x^2}{A^2}\implies 4x\le A^2+2x+\frac{x^2}{A^2}=\Big(A+\frac xA\!\Big)^2,$$

and we get the desired inequality by applying a square root and dividing by 2. Of course we don't have square root yet, so we can just keep it in this form. The point is that if $A^2>x$, then $A>\frac xA$, so $A>\frac12(A+\frac xA)$. But for each $y\in S(x)$, $y^2\le x\le\frac14(A+\frac xA)^2$, so $y\le\frac12(A+\frac xA)$. (Note that $a<b$ iff $a^2<b^2$ for $a,b\in\Bbb R^{\ge0}$.) Thus $\frac12(A+\frac x A)$ is an upper bound of $S(x)$ less than $A$, a contradiction. Therefore $A^2\le x$.

If $x=0$, then $S(0)=\{0\}$ so $\sup S(0)=0$ and thus $A^2=x$. If $x>0$ then $0<\min(x,1)^2<x$ so $\sup S(x)=A>0$. Thus $2A>A$ so if $A^2\le\frac x4$ then $2A\in S(x)$, a contradiction. Thus $A^2>\frac x4$.

For the final case, if $0<\frac x4\le A^2<x$ then $\frac 32A>0$, $x-A^2>0$, and $A^2-\frac x4\ge0$, so
$$0\le\frac{x-A^2}{[\frac 32\!A]^2}\Big(A^2-\frac x4\!\Big)=x-\frac{x^2A^{-2}+4x+4A^2}9=x-\Big(\!\frac{xA^{-1}+2A}3\!\Big)^2:=x-B^2,$$

so $B^2\le x$. Also $$B=\frac x{3A}+\frac{2A}3=A+\frac{x-A^2}{3A},$$ so $B>A$. Thus $B\in S(x)$ is greater than $A=\sup S(x)$, a contradiction. Thus $A^2=x$.